# How to read new Phoenix channel instance's state in Channel test case?

Tags: elixir, integration-testing, phoenix-framework, phoenix-channels, ex-unit

I have the following phoenix channel that handle an incoming message, broadcasts it and then updates the channel instance's `socket` state:

```
defmodule MyApp.MyChannel do
  use MyApp.Web, :channel

  def join("topic", _payload, socket) do
    {:ok, socket}
  end

  def handle_in("update", %{"new_number" => number_}, socket) do
    broadcast socket, "update", %{"new_number" => number_} 
    {:noreply, assign(socket, :current_number, number_)}
  end
  ...
end
```

I am trying to test the behavior of the `handle_in("update", ...)` function via this test case:

```
test "should broadcast new number and update the relevant instance's socket state", %{socket: socket} do
  push socket, "update", %{"new_number" => 356}
  assert_broadcast "update", %{"new_number" => 356}
  ## This is testing against the old state
  ## which is going to obviously fail
  assert socket.assigns[:current_number] == 356  
end
```

The issue here is that I can't find a way to get the new updated `socket` state inside the test case.

- There is no `assert_socket_state` function in the `Phoenix.ChannelTest` module and I can't find any function allowing to get the newest socket state
- I thought about defining a `handle_call` or a `handle_info` that returns the socket state but this means that I will have to get the channel's pid in order to call them.
- I thought about defining a `handle_in` for this purpose but I don't want to put in my channel with an introspection tool that is going to be available in production.

**How can I get the updated** `socket` **in the test case, after pushing the message?**

Comment: Does this work: `assert :sys.get_state(socket.channel_pid)[:current_number] == 356`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `socket` state contains a `channel_pid` entry that basically contains the `pid` of the channel.

The previous combined with the [`:sys.get_state/1`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/sys.html#get_state-1) function which takes the `pid` of a GenServer and returns its most recent `state` is the key!

Example, given a `socket` state inside a test case:

```
:sys.get_state(socket.channel_pid).assigns[:current_number]
```

**Credit goes to** [Dogbert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/320615/dogbert) for their comment on the question.